# Recursive sequence depending on the parameter

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

> For the given parameter $\mathbb R\ni t\geq 1$, the sequence is
>   defined recursively: $$a_1=t,\;\;a_{n+1}a_n=3a_n-2$$ $(a)$ Let $t=4$.
>   Prove the sequence $(a_n)$ converges and find its limit.
>
> $(b)$ Which parameters $t\geq 1$ is the sequence $(a_n)$ increasing
>   for?

My attempt:

> Bolzano-Weierstrass:A sequence converges if it is monotonous and
>    bounded

$$a_{n+1}a_n=3a_n-2\implies a_{n+1}=3-\frac{2}{a_n}$$
$(a)$

First few terms: $a_1=4,a_2=\frac{5}{2},a_3=\frac{11}{5}$

Assumption: the sequence is decreasing

Proof by induction:
the basis (n=1) is trivial: $\frac{5}{2}<4$

Assumption: $a_n<a_{n-1},\;\forall n\in\mathbb N$

Step: $$a_n<a_{n-1}\implies\frac{1}{a_n}\geq\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}\Bigg/\cdot(-2)$$
$$\iff-\frac{2}{a_n}\leq-\frac{2}{a_{n-1}}\iff \underbrace{3-\frac{2}{a_n}}_{a_{n+1}}\leq\underbrace{3-\frac{2}{a_{n-1}}}_{a_n}$$
The limit: $$L=3-\frac{2}{L}\implies L^2-3L+2=0$$
I take into account only $2$ because the parabola is convex and $$a_n\to L^-.$$
Then I have to prove: $a_n\geq 2\;\forall n\in\mathbb N$ after the formal computing: $a_{n+1}\geq 3-\frac{2}{2}=2$
$\underset{\implies}{\text{Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem}}(a_n)\to 2$

$(b)$ Since the sequence doesn't have to be convergent, only increasing:
$$a_2=3-\frac{2}{t}\geq t\implies t\in[1,2]$$
Then, it should follow inductively,analogously to $(a)$, this time it is increasing.
Is this correct?

Comment: That is not what Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem states.

Comment: @PeterForeman, I will correct that. May I ask what the name of that theorem is? Because our assistant told us 'that isn't the BW' from the lectures'.  I was confused by that because it has to be universal and when I searched in English, I found the same theorems as in our script with names switched.

Comment: There are quite a few Bolzano-Weierstrass theorems, but the one stated isn't any of the BW theorems. That is the monotone convergence theorem. Not sure if there is a census about its name, but in one of my favourite textbooks that is how it's named.

Comment: No need to worry about names of theorems as you have stated the result being used. Bolzano did in fact stress on the nature of monotone and bounded sequences. The name Bolzano-Weierstrass has become almost standard for stating that infinite bounded sets have at least one accumulation point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us find the general form for the sequence given by the recursion
$$
a_{n+1}=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}3&-2\\ 1&0
\end{bmatrix}
}_{}\cdot a_n\ ,
$$
where we use the Möbius action of matrices $2\times 2$ on scalars, given in general by 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d
\end{bmatrix}\cdot x
:=
\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\ ,
$$
see also [Möbius transformation, wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).

The special matrix $A$ used in the problem can be diagonalized,
$$
A=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\ 1/2&1
\end{bmatrix}}_{T}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}2&\\ &1
\end{bmatrix}}_{D}
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}2&-2\\-1&2
\end{bmatrix}}_{T^{-1}}
$$ 
and because $A^n=TD^nT^{-1}$ we get the general form for $a_n=A^n\cdot\begin{bmatrix}4\\1\end{bmatrix}$, and then passing to the element in the projective space, by taking the quotient, it is:
$$
a_n=\frac{6\cdot 2^n-2}{3\cdot 2^n-2}\ .
$$
It converges to $6/3=2$.

For the part (b) a similar study can be started, the general term being
$$
a_n(t)=
TD^nT^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}t\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}_{\Bbb P^1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\cdot 2^n-1 & -2\cdot 2^n+2\\
2^n-1 & -2\cdot 2^n+2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
t\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ considered in }
{\Bbb P^1} 
\ .
$$
I am stopping here...

Comment: Thanks. Never heard of the Möbius transformation and I learned something new! In your formula for $a_n$ the powers should be $n-1$ instead of $n$. Also please read my solution using elementary math.

Comment: @NeatMath Yes, the index is shifted, taking things strictly, this is an error. But well, maybe i will let is still as it is, there is no structural difference, and the formulas have a better shape. Yes, your way is also a good way!

Answer (score 1):

If you have already proven $a_n > 2, \forall n$ , then

Let $b_n=a_n-2$, $b_n>0$. $a_{n+1} = 3 - \frac{2}{a_n} \Rightarrow b_{n+1} + 2=3-\frac{2}{b_n+2} \Rightarrow b_{n+1} = \frac{b_n}{2+b_n} < \frac{b_n}{2}$.

Therefore as $n\to \infty, b_n \to 0, a_n \to 2.\blacksquare$

The next is pure hindsight based on dan_fulea's solution but I believe it can be useful when the two fixed points are distinct.

$a_{n+1} - 1 = 2-\frac{2}{a_n} = \frac{2(a_n - 1)}{a_n}$

$a_{n+1} - 2 = 1-\frac{2}{a_n} = \frac{a_n - 2}{a_n}$

Therefore $\frac{a_{n+1}-1}{a_{n+1}-2} = 2\cdot \frac{a_n-1}{a_n-2}$

$\frac{a_n-1}{a_n-2}$ is a geometric sequence with initial value $\frac{3}{2}$,

so $\frac{a_n-1}{a_n-2} = 2^{n-1} \frac{3}{2} = 1+\frac{1}{a_n-2} \Rightarrow a_n = 2+ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}\frac{3}{2}-1} = \frac{6\cdot 2^{n-1}-2}{3\cdot 2^{n-1}-2}.\blacksquare$

In general if there are two distinct fixed points $r$ and $s$ then the ratio $\frac{a_n-r}{a_n-s}$ is a geometric sequence.